# Css div relative but absolute

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overlay, caption

I would like to make a div child element as overlay for all the parent content,with parent width fixed. (an example could be the js captions you see on photo galleries usually)

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="overlay">overlay them</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
width:300px;
max-width:300px;
}
.child{
width:100%;
min-width:100%;
position:relative;
}
.overlay{
position: /*?? to make it cover like overlay all the .child so all the .parent content*/

}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ttUgM/1/

Comment: The overlay is typically inserted at the top level of the DOM, right after BODY (or after all content).

Comment: i'm not talking about body overlay , i'm talking about a relative overlay (relative to the element in which it is), you can call that caption if you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the `.parent` a `position:relative` and the `.overlay` a `position:absolute` this will allow you to position the `.overlay` relative to the `.parent`. Is that what you want?

Comment: sorry, yes, i think you gotach, let me test up

Comment: i tested up i'm on **boostrap**, overlay is inside **.row-fluid** element, and it brokes **row-fluid layout** adding **position:absolute;** to **.overlay**

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to position the `.overlay` besides `position:absolute`. Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: i didn't setted margin:0 auto; on first jsfiddle to the .overlay, and in this case i don't need position:relative; on .row-fluid (parent)